# Allow users to broadcast live streams through webcam

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webcam

I'm trying to create a website like Ustream using ruby on rails.

I want users to be able to turn on their webcams and broadcasts live. I also want them to be able to send out a link to their live broadcast. The broadcast will need to work cross-browser also.

How can I do this effectively using ruby on rails?

Please be as detailed as possible. I'm looking for most simple and efficient solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What options are you considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, so I apologies if this is not as specific as you may hope

---

**Live Streaming & Rails**

Rails really isn't designed for live-streaming

It's MVC structure is best used to interact with large data-sets, and is better suited to handling things like authentication, API's, data-driven applications, etc

The live-streaming functionality you seek is more in the realm of [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) & [socket.io](http://socket.io/), more specifically [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) architecture, whereby two connected devices can share data across a single connection

There are a number of options available, but they are limited unless you go down the proprietary route:

---

**TokBox**

[TokBox](http://tokbox.com/) is the safest bet for Rails apps - it uses a third-party API to connect the devices, and implements the connection on the front-end with Javascript & flash. We have actually implemented this before, and it's very simple to do - [it's all explained here](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/building-a-video-party-app-with-ruby-on-rails/)

Tokbox is now owned by Telefonica, and I believe are investing heavily to make their technology better available & higher quality to developers. So we'll have to see how it goes

---

**WebRTC**

This is more like a driver, but is the best quality of all the options. The only issue is that implementing this technology is actually pretty hard. Here is an [overview](http://tokbox.com/learn-about-webrtc) for you:

> WebRTC is an open-source project enabling plugin-free, Real Time
>   Communications (RTC) in the browser. It includes the fundamental
>   building blocks for high-quality communications such as network,
>   audio, and video components used in voice and video chat applications.

---

**Recommendations**

Having implemented TokBox before, I'd recommend you look at that. You can [see a tutorial about it here](http://railsfornovice.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/video-chatting-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: Thanks Rich for the detailed answer. TokBox looks promising.

Comment: It's good, but has its limitations, most notably with the quality :)